# PC stops after a couple of seconds

Tags: boot, power-supply, fan

Today, my trusty [DELL XPS 8300](https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/cty/pdp/spd/xps-8300?c=us) desktop PC did not start. First time after years of flawless operation and daily use.
It powered up and then powered down after a couple of seconds without reaching the BIOS password prompt. No audible sign of malfunction, no beep.

According to the manual, I would have expected a beep code:
[image]

I disconnected all cables, opened the enclosure and applied some vacuum cleaning.
I had a special eye at the fans. I cleaned the CPU cooler fan.

After this remedy, the PC starts again. Problem solved!

**My question:**

> What could be the root cause? Under which circumstances would a PC powersupply silently power down?

Comment: The dirt in the fan (and elsewhere) caused the CPU to quickly overheat and shut down. Fairly normal.

Comment: Without error beep?

Comment: Not all errors have beep codes.

Comment: It's failing POST, however it's not necessarily due to the CPU overheating if the system was off for more than 30min prior to POST failing, as a CPU won't thermal shutdown until it reaches 99C or 100C, which can't occur during the 2s - 3s POST unless it was running, thermal shutdown occurred, and upon immediately rebooting, POST failed. POST will fail for a variety of reasons from a poorly seated cable or component to thermal reasons, and if the CPU header and fan were caked in dust, that would be the likely issue; however, if not, it's more likely a cable and/or component was poorly seated.